# Why when adding from dictionary<string,string> to listBox and then selecting items in the listBox SelectedIndexChanged event there is error?

Tags: c#, winforms

at the top of form1

```
Dictionary<string, string> FileList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

in the constructor

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string g = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\rectangles.txt");
            FileList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(g);
            listBox1.DataSource = FileList.ToList(); 
        }
```

in the selected index event

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(FileList
        .Where(x => x.Key == ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem?.ToString())
        .Select(x => x.Value).First()
    );
        }
```

the exception error is on the lin e in the selected index event

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Sequence contains no elements
> Source=System.Core

and i see the items in the listBox but when trying to select another item then it's throwing the exception.

[image: listBox items after assigning the FileList to the DataSource in the constructor]

The full code :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
 using System.Drawing.Imaging;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
 using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;
 using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.ProgressBar;
    
 namespace Image_Crop
 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         System.Drawing.Image img = null;
         Rectangle rect;
         int pixelsCounter = 0;
         Color SelectedColor = Color.LightGreen;
         List<DrawingRectangle> DrawingRects = new List<DrawingRectangle>();
         Bitmap rectImage;
         int saveRectanglesCounter = 1;
         bool drawBorder = true;
         bool clearRectangles = true;
         bool saveRectangles = true;
         string rectangleName;
         Dictionary<string, string> FileList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    
         public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
    
             pictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"d:\Comparison\ConvertedBmp.bmp");
               
             img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"d:\Comparison\radar_without_clouds.jpg");
    
             checkBoxDrawBorder.Checked = true;
             checkBoxClearRectangles.Checked = true;
             checkBoxSaveRectangles.Checked = true;
    
             if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"d:\rectangles.txt"))
             {
                 string g = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\rectangles.txt");
                 FileList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(g);
                 listBox1.DataSource = FileList.ToList();
             }
         }
    
         public class DrawingRectangle
         {
             public Rectangle Rect => new Rectangle(Location, Size);
             public Size Size { get; set; }
             public Point Location { get; set; }
             public Control Owner { get; set; }
             public Point StartPosition { get; set; }
             public Color DrawingcColor { get; set; } = Color.LightGreen;
             public float PenSize { get; set; } = 3f;
         }
    
         private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
    
         }
    
         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             if (img == null)
             {
                 // Create image.
                 img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"d:\Comparison\ConvertedBmp.bmp");
             }
         }
    
         private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
         {
    
         }
    
         private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
         {
             if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
             DrawingRects.Add(new DrawingRectangle()
             {
                 Location = e.Location,
                 Size = Size.Empty,
                 StartPosition = e.Location,
                 Owner = (Control)sender,
                 DrawingcColor = SelectedColor // <= Shape's Border Color
             });
         }
    
         private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
         {
             if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
    
             var dr = DrawingRects[DrawingRects.Count - 1];
             if (e.Y < dr.StartPosition.Y) { dr.Location = new Point(dr.Rect.Location.X, e.Y); }
             if (e.X < dr.StartPosition.X) { dr.Location = new Point(e.X, dr.Rect.Location.Y); }
    
             dr.Size = new Size(Math.Abs(dr.StartPosition.X - e.X), Math.Abs(dr.StartPosition.Y - e.Y));
             pictureBox2.Invalidate();
         }
    
         private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
         {
             if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
    
             if (DrawingRects.Count > 0)
             {
                 // The last drawn shape
                 var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
                 if (dr.Rect.Width > 0 && dr.Rect.Height > 0)
                 {
                     rectImage = cropAtRect((Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image, dr.Rect);
                     if (saveRectangles)
                     {
                         rectangleName = @"d:\Rectangles\rectangle" + saveRectanglesCounter + ".bmp";
                         FileList.Add($"{dr.Location}, {dr.Size}", rectangleName);
                         string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
     FileList,
     Formatting.Indented // this for pretty print
 );
                         using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\rectangles.txt", false))
                         {
                             sw.Write(json);
                             sw.Close();
                         }
    
    
                         rectImage.Save(rectangleName);
                         saveRectanglesCounter++;
                     }
                     pixelsCounter = rect.Width * rect.Height;
                     pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    
                     // ListBox used to present the shape coordinates
                     listBox1.Items.Add($"{dr.Location}, {dr.Size}");
    
                     StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\Rectangles\rectangles.txt", true);
                     w.WriteLine(rectangleName.Substring(23) + " ===> " + $"{dr.Location}, {dr.Size}");
                     w.Close();
                 }
             }
         }
    
         private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
         {
             DrawShapes(e.Graphics);
         }
    
         private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
         {
             if (drawBorder)
             {
                 ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
             }
    
             if (rectImage != null && DrawingRects.Count > 0)
             {
                 var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
                 e.Graphics.DrawImage(rectImage, dr.Rect);
    
                 if (clearRectangles)
                 {
                     DrawingRects.Clear();
                     pictureBox2.Invalidate();
                 }
             }
         }
    
         private void DrawShapes(Graphics g)
         {
             if (DrawingRects.Count == 0) return;
             g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
             foreach (var dr in DrawingRects)
             {
                 using (Pen pen = new Pen(dr.DrawingcColor, dr.PenSize))
                 {
                     g.DrawRectangle(pen, dr.Rect);
                 };
             }
         }
    
         public Bitmap cropAtRect(Bitmap b, Rectangle r)
         {
             Bitmap nb = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
             using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(nb))
             {
                 g.DrawImage(b, -r.X, -r.Y);
                 return nb;
             }
         }
    
         private void checkBoxDrawBorder_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             if (checkBoxDrawBorder.Checked)
             {
                 drawBorder = true;
             }
             else
             {
                 drawBorder = false;
             }
    
             pictureBox1.Invalidate();
         }
    
         private void checkBoxClearRectangles_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             if (checkBoxClearRectangles.Checked)
             {
                 clearRectangles = true;
             }
             else
             {
                 clearRectangles = false;
             }
    
             pictureBox2.Invalidate();
         }
    
         private void checkBoxSaveRectangles_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
    
         }
    
         private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            var item = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem;
        var itemCast = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)item;
        pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(itemCast.Value);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I doubt that `.SelectedItem.ToString()` yields the expected result... If the dictionary key is "a" and the value is "b" then I'd expect, `[a, b]`.

Comment: [RectangleConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangleconverter) Class -- Your SelectedItem is a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`

Comment: still not sure how to solve it.  i edited my question and added also the full code.

Comment: @Jimi i tried but not sure how to use this RectangleConverter in this case.  i tried to string or from string.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama but it's working fine in the SelectedIndexChanged event when the application is running and when drawing rectangles. it's not working and throw the exception when running over the application and reading back the json file to the listBox in the constructor then it's throwing the exception in the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: OK, so consider the first item in the list has a key A and a value B. `.Where(x => x.Key == ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem?.ToString())` will filter items from `FileList` where the key (`"A"` for the first item) is equal to the selected item's string representation (`"[A, B]"` for the first value). Clearly `"A" == "[A, B]"` should resolve to `false` because they are not equal strings. In this way no items in `FileList` will ever match. It's not possible. Then you call `.First()` to get the first item of an empty list and boom... error.

Comment: What confuses me is that, when `.SelectedItem` isn't `null`, `SelectedItem` already holds the `KeyValuePair<string, string>` that you're trying to find in `FileList`. Why all the extra work rather than casting it from `object` to `KeyValuePair<string, string>`?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama it's working. should i make it as answer ? private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem;
            var itemCast = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)item;
            pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(itemCast.Value);
        }

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question :) I suggest you do that.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama i see now another problem with the new cast.  when the application is running first time and then i draw rectangles then select item in listBox it's throwing exception on the cast line : vae itemCast : System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Specified cast is not valid. and i see with the mouse that the selecteditem is the left side {X=66,Y=68}, {Width=211, Height=133} not the path to the file name.,

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama so with the cast it's working when loading from the file but then when saving new rectangles and select item it's throwing this exception and when without the casting as before the original code it was working it was throwing exception when loading and worked when running the application first time.

Comment: That's essentially a different question, but I suspect it's down to how you're adding new items. You should probably add them to `FilesList`. You should also handle the situation where `.SelectedItem` is null.

Comment: I solved it, it's working. i will post answer soon.